# Update Ubuntu 14

Tags: 14.04, disk-usage, update-alternatives

I want update my Ubuntu 14 to Ubuntu 16.
The problem is in my root directory. It consist of 7.3GB and I have only 300MB free space.
Can I update it using my home(where is my desctop) directory with more that 20GB free space?

Comment: Nope. Your root is too small.

Comment: Ok. Is it possible to change size of those directories now or only during installation?

Comment: There are probably hundreds of guides, here is one: https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions.